# What is the module of a rust file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Given a rust file in a cargo package, how do I get its absolute module name?

So, if I have a directory structure as follows:

```
Cargo.toml
/src/lib.rs
/src/foo.rs
/src/foo/bat.rs
```

these files might contain code snippets:

```
Cargo.toml
/src/lib.rs # mod foo;
/src/foo.rs # mod bar { mod bat; }
/src/foo/bat.rs # //! This is crate::foo::bar::bat
```

so I'm looking of a way of pointing at an `.rs` file and getting the absolute module path, so the outputs would be:

```
/src/lib.rs -> crate
/src/foo.rs -> crate::foo
/src/foo/bat.rs -> crate::foo::bar::bat
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is guaranteed that a file is only loaded as a module once, though it's a bit weird to do it, so that means you aren't guaranteed that a file would have a single crate path. What are you actually trying to do with this path?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is the underlying problem, where this is needed? You might be able to use [`ctor`](https://crates.io/crates/ctor) or [`inventory`](https://crates.io/crates/inventory) to build a registry of paths to modules. However, note that `ctor` (which `inventory` also depends on) has a serious [issue (47384)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47384), which issues results in you having to build your own registry manually.

Comment: @loganfsmyth The only way I know of loading a file twice is to symlink it, so there are two different paths that lead to the same file.  If that is not the case I would really like to know the details as we have made design decisions based on this assumption.

Comment: @vallentin The use case is running the tests most relevant to a file whenever a file is saved, specifically the unit tests for the module.  `cargo test` takes a module and a package as a filter.  As far as I know there is no way to get it to use a file as a filter.

Comment: You can `mod thing;` in multiple places, creating a `thing` module in multiple places. For example `mod thing; mod other { mod thing; }`, or a `foo.rs`, `bar.rs`, and `thing.rs`, if both `foo` and `bar` had a `mod thing;` then there would be two copies of that file loaded as a module. Usually you'd put `mod` one place and then `use` everywhere else, but that isn't a requirement.

Comment: i am also facing same question, but it seems rust module system is designed for experts only.